# Definition of binary variable in Pyomo is not working

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm new to Pyomo (and optimization) and am trying to reproduce a simple approach (see comment from Fengyuan-Shi on https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/821) to create a maximum constraint using the Big M method and binary variables. The code returns the correct answer, but the variables u_1 and u_2, which are supposed to be binary (taking values of 0 or 1 only) are actually taking values *between* 0 and 1. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
import pyomo.environ as pyomo

m = pyomo.ConcreteModel()

m.x = pyomo.Param(initialize=5) 
m.y = pyomo.Param(initialize=9) 
m.z = pyomo.Var(domain = pyomo.NonNegativeReals)
m.u_1 = pyomo.Var(domain = pyomo.Binary)
m.u_2 = pyomo.Var(domain = pyomo.Binary)
m.M = pyomo.Param(initialize=1e3) # Big M

m.o = pyomo.Objective(expr = m.z + 8)
m.cons = pyomo.ConstraintList()


# ensure z is the maximum of x and y, per comment from Fengyuan Shi on https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/821
# =============================================================================
m.cons.add(m.x <= m.z) 
m.cons.add(m.y <= m.z) 
m.cons.add(m.x >= m.z - m.M*(1-m.u_1)) 
m.cons.add(m.y >= m.z - m.M*(1-m.u_2))
m.cons.add(m.u_1 + m.u_2 >= 1)  

m.pprint()

solver = pyomo.SolverFactory('ipopt')
status = solver.solve(m)

print("Status = %s" % status.solver.termination_condition)


for v in m.component_objects(pyomo.Var, active=True):
    print ("Variable component object",v, v.value)
```

When the code is run, the output is:
*Variable component object z 8.999999912504697 (correct, the maximum of x = 5 and y=9)
Variable component object u_1 0.5250908817936364 (expected this to be either 0 or 1)
Variable component object u_2 0.5274112114061761 (expected this to be either 0 or 1)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construct appears correct.  You need to use a different solver.

`ipopt` is typically used for non-linear problems and it **does not support** integer requirements (which includes binary assignment).  Specifically, it only supports *continuous* variables.

The problem you have is completely linear, so you should be using a linear solver that supports MIP formulations.  Your problem is a "Mixed Integer Program" because of the binary requirements.  I'd suggest `cbc` or `glpk`, both of which are freeware.

Comment: Super.  If this answered your question, it is customary to close out the question by accepting the answer (checkmark near it) and/or up-voting it.